# How is it possible to stop at the first failure when using dataProvider? ( phpUnit )

Tags: php, phpunit

I created a data provider for a test case. It provides smaller and then longer arrays as an input for the test function. I would like to stop at the first error, because the error message gets harder to understand for larger inputs. But I would like to test for large inputs as well.

```php
function testFunction(array $inputOne, array $inputTwo) {...}

function myDataProvider() {
    return [
        [[1,2], [3,4]],
        [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,10]],
        [<<LARGE ARRAY>>, <<LARGE ARRAY>>],
    ];
}
```

Comment: There is a stop-on-error setting in the phpunit configuration and as an option in the phpunit command line runner. Do you mean that? (one for error, one for warning and one for test failures, one for risky etc.) Perhaps also [edit] in how you run the tests and which phpunit version.